# Convert vcxproj to xcodeproj

Tags: ios, xcode, file-conversion

Is there anyway/tool that can directly convert a Visual Studio `vcxproj` file to an `xcodeproj` ?

Comment: Wild guess: no. This would only really be useful for projects that don't rely on any specific features of either IDE / environment (pure C libraries or such), which doesn't sound like much of a target market.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, or completely off, but I'm thinking that even though compiling with VC++ isn't 100% platform dependent, that moving it over to an Apple IDE might not be doable without porting the actual sourcecode. I don't think there is any sort of automated tool to do so.

Comment: Actually, did a search, turns out Wine has a makefile generator that helps port the code to Unix platforms, this may be useful, look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870533/where-can-i-find-a-tool-to-convert-a-vs-solution-to-a-gcc-makefile)